# Displaying hotkey underline on custom styled button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have changed the styles of my `Buttons` in WPF. All that is working as intended, but is there a way to get the classic hotkey underscore that you display by pressing ALT to display? If I put an underscore in the `Button` text, it always displays it.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource THFont}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f00000" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 10 0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#f00000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#f00000">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="10 0 10 0" Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#BD0000" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#BD0000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template should include a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource THFont}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f00000" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 10 0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#f00000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#f00000">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextElement.FontSize="12" Margin="10 0 10 0"
                                     Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#BD0000" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#BD0000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: By the way. It would be a different question, but since you seem on top of it, The IsMouseOver trigger works, on most buttons, but on some it doesn't. Nothing apparently different about them. Any idea just like that?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.